# How to display hidden form field based on select box choice

Tags: javascript, forms, bootstrap-form-helper

I want from the first dropdown when i select top to open the c92 dropdown
and when i select low to open the c97 dropdown with bootstrap.

I don't want to have breaks between the hidden lists. Any thoughts?

```
<div class="form-group c86 required" data-cid="c86">
   <label class="control-label" for="c86">Product</label>
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i> </span>
      <select class="form-control" id="c86" name="c86" data-rule-required="true">
         <option value="">- Select -</option>
         <option value="top">top</option>
         <option value="low">low</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group c92 " data-cid="c92">
   <label class="control-label" for="c92" style="display: none">Mattress</label>
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> </span>
      <select class="form-control" id="c92" name="c92" style="display: none">
         <option value="">- Select -</option>
         <option value="One">One</option>
         <option value="Two">Two</option>
         <option value="Three">Three</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group c97 " data-cid="c97">
   <label class="control-label" for="c97" style="display: none">Sofa</label>
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> </span>
      <select class="form-control" id="c97" name="c97" style="display: none">
         <option value="">- Select -</option>
         <option value="One">One</option>
         <option value="Two">Two</option>
         <option value="Three">Three</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this something like what your after?.

ps: You can run the code snippet..

```js
var 
  c86 = $('#c86'),
  c92 = $('#c92');

function selChange() {
  var 
    v = c86.find('option:selected').val(),
    vtop = c92.find('option:selected').val();
  $('[data-cid=c92]').toggleClass('hidden',
    v !== 'top');
  $('[data-cid=c97]').toggleClass('hidden',
    v !== 'low');
  console.log(vtop, v);
  $('[data-cid=c_one]').toggleClass('hidden',
    !(v === 'top' && vtop === 'One'));                               
}

c86.change(selChange);
c92.change(selChange);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group c86 required" data-cid="c86">
  <label class="control-label" for="c86">Product</label>
  <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i> </span>
    <select class="form-control" id="c86" name="c86" data-rule-required="true">
      <option  value="">- Select -</option>
      <option  value="top">top</option>
      <option  value="low">low</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>




<div class="hidden form-group c92 " data-cid="c92">
  <label class="control-label" for="c92">Mattress</label>
  <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> </span>
    <select class="form-control" id="c92" name="c92">
      <option  value="">- Select -</option>
      <option  value="One">One</option>
      <option  value="Two">Two</option>
      <option  value="Three">Three</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hidden form-group c97 " data-cid="c97">
  <label class="control-label" for="c97">Sofa</label>
  <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> </span>
    <select class="form-control" id="c97" name="c97">
      <option  value="">- Select -</option>
      <option  value="One">One</option>
      <option  value="Two">Two</option>
      <option  value="Three">Three</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hidden form-group c_one " data-cid="c_one">
  <label class="control-label" for="c_one">Test 2</label>
  <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> </span>
    <select class="form-control" id="c_one" name="c_one">
      <option  value="">- Select -</option>
      <option  value="A">Top One</option>
      <option  value="B">Was</option>
      <option  value="C">Selected</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I copy-paste your solution but it doesn't run. Script inside head <script> var c86 = $('#c86'); c86.change(function () { var v = c86.find('option:selected').val(); $('[data-cid=c92]').toggleClass('hidden', v !== 'top'); $('[data-cid=c97]').toggleClass('hidden', v !== 'low'); }); </script> and the divs inside body. With run code snippet it runs. One more question for your code. If i have a fourth dropdown which is dependent on thrird dropdown selection how the code would be? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure what you mean it doesn't run,.. Try running the above code Snippet.. If it doesn't run after you copy and paste into your solution, you will need to check your console for errors etc.   I've done an update to do 3 selects, if you select  'top' then 'one' another select will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Put the id on the div wrapper and hide it, use `onchange` event to call the function `displayForm`, when the select changes it checks the value and then shows/hides the wrappers elements by id.

```js
function displayForm(elem){
   if(elem.value == "top") {
     document.getElementById('c97').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('c92').style.display = "block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('c92').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('c97').style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i> </span>
<select class="form-control" onchange="displayForm(this)" id="c86" name="c86" data-rule-required="true"
  <option  value="">- Select -</option>
  <option  value="top">top</option>
  <option  value="low">low</option>

  </select>
</div>

</div>

<div id="c92" style="display: none" class="form-group c92 " data-cid="c92">
  <label class="control-label" for="c92" >Mattress</label>

<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> </span>
<select class="form-control"  name="c92"   
    >
  <option  value="">- Select -</option>
  <option  value="One">One</option>
  <option  value="Two">Two</option>
  <option  value="Three">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>

</div>

<div id="c97" class="form-group c97 " style="display: none" data-cid="c97">
  <label class="control-label" for="c97" >Sofa</label>

<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> </span>
<select class="form-control"  name="c97" 
    >
  <option  value="">- Select -</option>
  <option  value="One">One</option>
  <option  value="Two">Two</option>
  <option  value="Three">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>

</div>
```